# Sql query to fetch product having highest sale group wise

Tags: mysql

```
Id|product_name|product_group    |sale_Amnt(INR)
------------------------------------------------
 1|  p1       |   Cosmetic       |4485
 2|  p2       |   Cosmetic       |8525
 3|  p3       |   Health         |12589
 4|  p4       |   Health         |5895
 5|  p5       |   Home Appliances|9858
 6|  p6       |   Home Appliances|11589
```

I want a sql query to fetch product_group having highest sale amount

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this;)

```
select t1.*
from yourtable t1
inner join (
    select max(`sale_Amnt(INR)`) as `sale_Amnt(INR)`, product_group 
    from yourtable
    group by product_group
) t2 on t2.product_group = t1.product_group and t2.`sale_Amnt(INR)` = t1.`sale_Amnt(INR)`
```

The result of this query is following:

```
| Id | product_name |   product_group | sale_Amnt(INR) |
|----|--------------|-----------------|----------------|
|  2 |           p2 |        Cosmetic |      8525      |
|  3 |           p3 |          Health |     12589      |
|  6 |           p6 | Home Appliances |     11589      |
```

Answer (score 0):

USE INNER QUERY TO GROUP BY AND ORDER BY

SELECT * FROM (SELECT product_group,SUM(sale_Amnt) FROM TABLE  GROUP BY product_group ORDER BY SUM(sale_Amnt) DESC ) R LIMIT 1

Comment: if you want to get all products order by product group execute only the inner select